# Django multiple queryset and iterate over template

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    region_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)

class Enquiry(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    region_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=False, blank=False)
    date_of_enquiry = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

template should look like

```
enquiry_id  Company_name  region_id  date_of_enquiry
1               xyz           abc          12/2/2015    
2               mno           pqr          12/2/2015
```

Both model are referenced by the customer_id

Sorry for the inconvenience,

Let me clear the doubt here

I am querying from the Enquiry table with the filters as region_id and status like this(matching loggedin user region_id with enquiry table region_id and status of the enquiry table)
    received_object= Enquiry.objects.filter(region_id=user_obj.region_id, status="Enquiry Sent")

i get the output like this

```
enquiry_id    region_id  date_of_enquiry
1               abc          12/2/2015    
2               pqr          12/2/2015
```

but i want to show the company name also in the table

so i wrote the query as

userAdded_Object = []

for item in received_object:
    userAdded_object.append(Customer.objects.get(user_id=item.customer_id))

and iterating two query set in single for loop over template is not working

Comment: And ? What's the question exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very, very basic question that you can almost pull directly from the examples in the docs; please take the time to read them. That's why your question is being downvoted.

Questions needing help with code should at minimum provide the code that you've tried that isn't working. Asking people to write your code for you is frowned upon, but I'm feeling generous this morning so:

View:

```
def your_view(request):
    enquiries = Enquiry.objects.select_related('customer').all()
    return render(request, 'your-template.html', {'enquiries': enquiries})
```

Table:

```
<table>
    {% for enquiry in enquiries %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ enquiry.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ enquiry.customer.company_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ enquiry.region }}</td>
        <td>{{ enquiry.date_of_enquiry }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% empty %}
    <tr>
        <td>Sorry, no enquiries.</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

However, your `customer` field on `Enquiry` points to `User`, not `Customer`, so you'll need to fix that. You really should work through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) if you haven't already.